# Console.log each array value after x seconds

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to console.log each value from a array, but with a delay after each log. It seems it's only waiting 3 seconds, than firing the code logging all at once. Is there any way I could simply log each one after 3 seconds each?

Here's my code:

```js
//Dummy data
const CoordArray = new Array(7).fill(0).map((i, index) => ({XCoord:index, YCoord: index}))

CoordArray.forEach(function(CoordObject) {

  //console.log(key, obj[key]);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(CoordObject.XCoord + " " + CoordObject.YCoord);
  }, 3000);
})
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't block, and the loop is executed within less than a millisecond. Then after 3 secs the callbacks are executed practically in a bunch because they have the same delay.

Comment: Add `i` as a parameter to your function, and use `3000 * i` as a delay

Comment: you could do the iteration using `setInterval()`, or you could use the index from .forEach to specify each timeout length eg: `3000*i`

Comment: Thanks guys/girls.

Comment: Whats the need for the clearTimeout() though? I commented it like "//clearT.." and no difference(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
const arr = ['5', '6', '7']
interval = 3000 //  = 3s
;

arr.forEach(function(el, index) {
  var run = setTimeout(function() {

    // console each element inside array
    console.log(el);

    clearTimeout(run);
  }, interval * index);
});
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the example. Will accept when it lets me in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
const CoordArray = new Array(7).fill(0).map((i, index) => ({XCoord:index, YCoord: index}));
var interval = 3000;
var inc = 1;

CoordArray.forEach(function(CoordObject) {
  var run = setTimeout(function() {

    console.log(CoordObject.XCoord + " " + CoordObject.YCoord);
    clearTimeout(run);

  }, interval * inc);

  inc = inc + 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this example with the XCoord:index.